# TYPO3 tx_news limit to language results to "ERROR: Language was not allowed."

Tags: localization, typo3, tx-news

TYPO3 7.6.18, tx_news 6.0.0

I have a editor limited to spanish. Translation of normal Content Elements works without problems.

Translation of News-Records leads to

```
Sorry, you didn't have proper permissions to perform this change.

ERROR: Language was not allowed.
```

and thus no translation possible. Any hints?

Comment: There is a problem, where Typo3 first copies the dataset and then tries to change the language, which will not work, because the copied dataset is in another language which the user is not allowed to edit. Cant tell if its the same bug, but this ext is worth a try: https://github.com/BenjaminBeck/bdm_bugfix_translatecopy

Comment: Thx for the hint, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: You mean you have editor user of typo3 BE? please explain in details. so we can help you.

Comment: Yes, Backend-User. Can edit page, content an news-records in spanish. Pages work, Content elements work. News Article are translated but cannot be edited due to the blocking `ERROR: Language was not allowed`.

Comment: Hm, I tested with a fresh 8.7.1 installation, same problem.

Comment: One more thing: when a news has no images attached, it works. The restricted editor is allowed to edit.